# Declare a SystemVerilog variable with type depending on a parameter

Tags: parameters, verilog, system-verilog, parameterized-types

I want to write reusable SystemVerilog code so I need to have in module one variable with type, depending on a parameter (not different bus WIDTH, but different structs). Maybe it is possible to have one parametrized structure or to have different structures but in this case how to declare variable selecting needed struct as a type. Different structs could be declared in generte-if blocks, but they will be local to it blocks, so outside can't to get them. Maybe type conversion might help somehow.

P. S. Interfaces are not allowed to use as well as defines (macros are allowed).

Code example, I want to achieve:

```
typedef struct packed
{
  logic a;
  logic b;
} str_s;

typedef struct packed
{
  logic a;
  logic b;
  logic c;
} str_s_with_c;

// A is a parameter
generate
if (A == "ON")
   str_s_with_c array;

if (A == "OFF")
   str_s array;
endgenerate

assign array.a = 1'b1;

logic t;

assign t = array.a;
```

or

```
generate
if (A == "ON")
begin
   typedef struct packed
   {
     logic a;
     logic b;
   } str_s;
end

if (A == "OFF")
begin
   typedef struct packed
   {
     logic a;
     logic b;
     logic c;
   } str_s;
end
endhenerate

str_s array;

array.a = 1.b1;
```

Comment: It might help to take a step back and explain what you are trying to accomplish and how you intend to use the different structure types. See https://xyproblem.info. What you are describing is almost like class inheritance, which you can use for testbenches, but not generally available for synthesis.

Answer (score 2):

A usual way of doing it is to pass struct as a parameter type to the module instance.

```
module inst#(type struct_t=int)();
    struct_t v;  
endmodule

typedef struct packed
{
  logic a;
  logic b;
} str_s;

typedef struct packed
{
  logic a;
  logic b;
  logic c;
} str_s_with_c;

module top;
  inst #(.struct_t(str_s)) inst1();
  inst #(.struct_t(str_s_with_c)) inst2();
endmodule
```

Answering the comment below for a single instance. In this case you can use a `generate` block, instantiating the module conditionally:

```
module top #(ON=1)
    typedef struct packed
    {
        logic a;
        logic b;
    } str_s;
    typedef struct packed
    {
        logic a;
        logic b;
        logic c;
    } str_s_with_c;

  if (ON == 1) begin: ON1
    inst #(.struct_t(str_s)) inst1();
  end
  else begin: ON0
    inst #(.struct_t(str_s_with_c)) inst2();
  end
endmodule
```

One caveat. You'd better declare the structs outside of the generate statements. LRM does not prevent you from declaring them inside, but this feature is not implemented in at least some of the compilers.

Comment: "int" in "type struct_t=int" is like a default type for struct here?

Is it possible to declare struct not in top module, but in other module and how to access them in this case and pass as parameters?

Comment: *int* is just a default type, which you can change to your like. sructs have to be declared in such a way that they are visible at the time of instantiation of *inst*. They can also be declared inside module *top* before instantiation of *inst* or in a system verilog *package*.

Comment: Okey, thanks! But there is one problem - in my top-module I have only one instance of module (not two as in your code _inst1_ and _inst2_). And I need to put there structure type depends on parameter.

Unfortunately it is not possible to pass top-module parameters to packages, but my structs have these parameters @Serge

Comment: I added a possible solution for this issue as well.

Comment: Yeah, I see. But what if there are 2 parameters so 4 possible combinations of them. And there are a lot of ports in this module (which mostly will be the same for all parameters - only struct type will differ). Maybe macro can help...

Answer (score 1):

You can declare variables local to generate blocks and access them with a block name.

```
typedef struct packed
{
  logic a;
  logic b;
} str_s;

typedef struct packed
{
  logic a;
  logic b;
  logic c;
} str_s_with_c;

// A is a parameter
if (A == "ON") begin : bname
   str_s_with_c array;
end 
else if (A == "OFF") begin :  bname
   str_s array;
end

assign bname.array.a = 1'b1;

logic t;

assign t = bname.array.a;
```

Note that if you want to access `array.c`, that will have to be guarded with a generate-if as well.

```
if (A == "ON") begin 
  always @(posedge clk)
    x = bname.array.c;
end 
else if (A == "OFF") begin 
  always @(posedge clk)
     x = something_else;
end
```

Comment: Is accessing to generate blocks with it names is synthesizable?

Comment: It should be; it's no different than accessing a struct member. Hierarchical references that go outside a module are generally _not_ synthesizable.

Comment: I have issues with those constructs with one of the EDA vendor synthesizer tool